# Android SDK and Developer Guide Offline or PDF

Tags: android, pdf, documentation

Where can I get PDF version of Android SDK docs and developer guide. Saw a posting that installed sdk has the html docs, mine does not.  Is this a separate download. any eclipse update  for this? Thanks

Comment: Visit http://dl.google.com/android/repository/docs-24_r01.zip that's where the docs are located.. I spotted this while I was downloading docs from sdk manager

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think only HTML is available and you get it by installing the Documentation using the Android SDK tool:

[image]

(See the 4th item in the list).

Comment: Great thanks. Everyone please do this. It will save lots of time, and make for better questions too.

Comment: Could you indicate where people will find this in eclipse after doing the update?

Comment: I read the documentation by opening .../android-sdk/docs/index.html with my browser (via a link from my Desktop).  Within Eclipse you only really have access to the API Reference by pressing Shift-F2 above an Android class.

Comment: Android 4.1.2 doesn't have option to download.

Comment: Android 6.0, API 23, it works!

Answer (score 21):

You can find the pdf's for most sections here
The website has been split into sections for each book.

https://docand.com/

```
Design .......................  https://docand.com/android-design-methods-book/
Training......................  https://docand.com/training-in-android-book/
Android Components............  https://docand.com/a-guide-to-android-api-components-book/
Google Services...............  https://docand.com/android-google-available-services-book/
Distribution Methods........... https://docand.com/android-distribution-methods-book/
Tools of the Android Developer  https://docand.com/tools-of-the-android-developer-book/
```

The sections are all available as a preview and as a download for free.

Comment: It's no more free. The free download is only a sample and full copy asks for a price.

Answer (score 16):

I have started putting together the updated dev guide into pdf.

You can find the first part here:
http://sirelanta.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-dev-guide-pdf-and-doc.html

other parts will be added later

Comment: This PDF looks much better than the other ones on this thread. Not to mention you've posted a DOCX along with it (very handy). The one by Yourfriend returns "Access Denied" (after a "Malware Detected" warning from Chrome), and the one by Loman has some extra branding added to it that I don't care for.

Comment: i need it on kindle