# Android developers guide

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android SDK and Developer Guide Offline or PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974309/android-sdk-and-developer-guide-offline-or-pdf)

Can anyone tell me if there is text(tutorial) from http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html in PDF format or at least in full screen view because its so hard to read this way.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.4shared.com/office/qXsU49Nz/Android-The-Developers-Guide.html) you go.

Also, [here](http://nytratech.com/index.php/android/20-android-sdk-dev-guide-in-pdf).

;)